# Recursion of a number if it is in ascending order in Racket without using list

Tags: racket

This program is forbidden to use any kinds of list. I tried the following method but it is crazy.

```scm
(define (order2 number2)
  (cond ((remainder number2 10) 1)
        (else (order3 number3))))

(define (order3 number3)
  (cond ((< number3 10) number3)
        (else
         (define (order4 number4)
           (cond (< remainder (quotient number4 10)))
           (else (order4 (quotient number4)))))))
))
```

Comment: There are lots of syntax errors in your code. Eg. `define` need to be right after the lambda list or at top level. The `else` doesn't do anything since `define` is a side effect and doesn't compute anything. What do you mean without `list`? Numbers are not lists. You have two numbers so no recursion needed. I don't understand what the challenge is here. BY any change did you mean digits in some base?

Comment: I tried 100 times to do it recursive way and our professor wanted all the pre conditions, I understand the errors with the define thing but can you give me the idea of how you can do recursively. I looked at online but did not really help.

Comment: As I mentioned I don't understand the task. Could you supply example usages with expected output or a better description of how it is supposed to work?